# Angular best practices for layouts

Tags: angularjs, authentication, layout

I have an admin dashboard application called dashboard.html initiated with its own angular module. This application has an consistent layout with n header bar at the top, left bar navigation etc. When the route changes only the content container gets updated and the rest of the layout stays unaffected.

My problem is that the login page, with a completely different layout, without the header bars and navigation.

Currently I'm solving this issue by creating an login.html file with its own module, when the user successfully login, I redirect them to the dashboard.html app.

Is this a general used approach or is there a clean way of doing it in a single application, by just changing the routes and not redirecting to different apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use angular UIrouter for doing this.

have look at this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/thardy/eD3MU/.

```
   <div ui-view="main"></div>



angular.module('myApp', ['ui.state'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$routeProvider',  
    function ($stateProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('test', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '/test',
                views: {
                    'main': {
                         template:  '<h1>Hello!!!</h1>' +
                                    '<div ui-view="view1"></div>' +
                                    '<div ui-view="view2"></div>'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('test.subs', {
                url: '',
                views: {
                    'view1@test': {
                        template: "Im View1"
                    },
                    'view2@test': {
                        template: "Im View2"
                    }
                }
            });
    }])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($rootScope,   $state, $stateParams) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
        $state.transitionTo('test.subs');
    }]);
```

You can create main views and sub-views into your app, for your app you can create main views for login and dashboard pages, and then you can load sub-views in your dashboard page as required.